# How to linearize a hyperbola

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, linear-transformations, linearization

If a hyperbola is given by

$$\frac{y^2}{a^2}-\frac{x^2}{b^2} = 1$$

rewriting it as a function of x we have that

$$y(x) = a \sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{b^2}}$$

is there a function $f(y)$ for which when I use it I will get a linear function on the graph $f(y)\space vs\space x$?

Comment: use binomial expansion

Comment: Try $f(y)=b \sqrt{\dfrac{y^2}{a^2}-1}$, though you might get two lines

Comment: What are you trying to determine from the linear graph?

Comment: There is a set of points that I need to fit, so I will use the least square method to find a and b that best fit my data

Comment: Transforming a graph through a function to be able to use least-squares is seriously _add hoc_: depending on the choice of function, different parts of the graph can be given wildly varying weights, with divergent results.  Usually least-squares is trying to minimize some well-defined quantity (e.g. error variance).  If you want a true least-squares fit of a hyperbola, you will need to go through the process of finding the dependence of the cumulative squared error as a function of $a$ and $b$, and then varying these parameters to minimize it.